# React multiple instances of same component are getting the same callback

Tags: reactjs, callback

I have a React Component that is only executing the first callback of the first Component instance, even if I click the second or third component. Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './checkbox.module.css';

interface CheckboxProps {
  initialState: boolean;
  onToggle: () => void;
}

const Checkbox: React.FC<CheckboxProps> = ({ initialState, onToggle }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(initialState);

  const handleChange = () => {
    const newChecked = !checked;
    setChecked(newChecked);
    onToggle();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        className={styles.switch}
        type="checkbox"
        id="switch"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <label className={styles['switch-label']} htmlFor="switch">Toggle</label>
    </>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

CSS code:

```css
.switch {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.switch-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 51.2px; 
  height: 25.6px; 
  background: rgb(241, 44, 44);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; 
  left: 4px; 
  width: 17.6px; 
  height: 17.6px; 
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 70.4px; 
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.switch:checked + .switch-label {
  background: #a5ce1e;
}

.switch:checked + .switch-label:after {
  left: calc(100% - 4px); 
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.switch-label:active:after {
  width: 22.4px; 
}
```

If I use my component like this, React Only executes the callback of the first component even if I click the second or the third component

```
<div>
<Checkbox key={1} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("One")}} />
<Checkbox key={2} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("Two")}} />
<Checkbox key={3} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("Three")}} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute is meant to be unique within an HTML document, so having multiple elements with the same ID can lead to conflicts.

```
      <Checkbox key={1} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("One")}} id={'one'}/>
      <Checkbox key={2} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("Two")}} id={'two'}/>
      <Checkbox key={3} initialState={false} onToggle={()=>{console.log("Three")}} id={'three'}/>
```

Use this instead hardcode 'switch' all your input

```
<>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id={id}
    checked={checked}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  <label htmlFor={id}>Toggle</label>
</>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and providing the solution!  
After carefully reviewing the code and discussing the issue, it became clear that the error was caused by using the same `id` attribute for multiple checkboxes within the component.